# Data Population for Windows Phone: Advice on best practice

Tags: windows-phone

So I've created my model, a single class that holds a few different string objects. What I now need to do is create a collection of these model objects to display to the user when they access the app.

This collection will be around 40 to 50 objects in size. Im just wondering what is the best practice to define these objects in windows phone mango? I know i could just simply create a class that creates these 50 objects at run time in code, writing all the different object's data in a loooong method. This is not how I want to do it however, it will look really messy.

My idea was to enter all the data from the model objects into an xml file instead. I will then read in the xml data and create the objects collection in a loop at run time. I was then thinking of entering these objects in a local database and from then on reading the data from the database and not the xml.
So in essense, on the apps first use, it will read data from xml and save to database
and then for all subsequent uses of app, it will read data from database.

Is there a better technique to do this? is xml the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just going to have around 40-50 objects, I wouldn't recommend to use the local database. Even though sqllite (the database supported by windows phone 7.1 mango) is a reduced version of sql server, it's still a resource hog, and you should only use it when dealing with large collections of data, where you think that data will grow and grow over time, or when having complex relationships in several tables where you need to handle lots of scenarios.

For smaller sets of data, I'd follow the approach that you mentioned, reading data from xml, parsing it and then creating the objects. You can use linq to xml which works great, you don't need to create difficult parsing code and it's highly maintanable.

If you need to later persist the information (so that you don't have to load the data each time your app starts), you can save the object list in isolated storage and re-read it later on.. remember always that data that goes to iso storage must be serializable.

Well, those are my recommendations, hope this helps!

Comment: Agreed. Note that the local database is SqlCe, not SQLite.

Comment: Sounds like good advice! I'm going to try that so and see what happens. Cheers.